# How to truncate yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd in xAxis of Django Chartit chart?

Tags: python, django

I want to remove the `YYYY` from the x-axis date `YYYY-MM-DD`, because the chart is showed in a small area. For example, `2018-09-04` should be `09-04`. I'm not sure whether any existing method can be used for this, Could somebody help?

I'm using `Django version 2.0`, `django-chartit 0.2.9`, and `Python 3.7.0`.

```
def get_block_chart(self):
    blockpivotdata = DataPool(
        series=[{
            'options': {
                'source': Block.objects         
                    .annotate(date=TruncDay('timestamp'))     # Truncate to day and add to select list
                    .values('date')                           # Group By day
                    .annotate(num=Count('hash'))              # Select the count of the grouping
                    .values('date', 'num')                    # select day and num
                    .order_by('date')
            },
            'terms': [
                'date',
                'num'
            ]
        }]
    )

    return Chart(
        datasource=blockpivotdata,
        series_options=[{
            'options': {
                'type': 'line',
                'stacking': False
            },
            'terms': {
                'date': [
                    'num',
                ]
            }
        }],
        chart_options={
            'title': {
                'text': 'Block Count Chart'},
            'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Date'}},
            'yAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Block'}},
            'legend': {
                'enabled': False},
            'credits': {
                'enabled': False}},
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Later I find a solution for this, and just want to paste here in case anyone need it. The method is to use `objects.raw()` and format it by SQL query `to_char(timestamp,'MM-dd') as niceday`:

```
blockpivotdata = DataPool(
    series=[{
        'options': {
            'source': Block.objects.raw("select 1 as hash, to_char(timestamp,'MM-dd') as niceday, "
                                        "max(total_difficulty) as total_difficulty, "
                                        "date(DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp)) as date, count(hash) as num "
                                        "from blockchain_block "
                                        "group by DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp),niceday order by date")
        },
        'terms': [
            'niceday',
            'num',
            'total_difficulty',
        ]
    }]
)
```

Note: I'm using PostgreSQL here.
And here is an alive demo for this solution: https://grinexplorer.net